# I stayed 3 months over my period in schengen. Can I go back within a month with a new passport?

Tags: europe, international-travel, schengen-visas, overstaying, passport-stamps

I was in Europe (Schengen) between November 2017 - December 2018. I extended my stay there and had to leave on august 20 however I fell in love and stayed with a woman three months and 2 weeks and left on December fifth.
Right now I have  a new passport that does not have the stamp from where I came in and left the Schengen area.
Will I be able to come back in January?

Comment: Where did you enter and exit Schengen? Some countries record entries and exits electronically, while others don't. Also, did anything happen when you exited Schengen?

Answer (score 7):

The [Schengen 90/180 day rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work) applies to you as an individual human being, not to your passport. You are not allowed to stay longer just because you get a new passport. It is possible that you won't be caught, but it is very much not allowed.

If you already overstayed (three months and 2 weeks sounds longer than 90 days), that may make it difficult for you to return to the Schengen area anytime soon, as you'd already have a documented history of not complying with immigration rules.

I'd add that the 90/180 rule is a maximum, not an invitation to use every possible minute you have in the Schengen area. You can still be denied entry even if you comply with the rule if they believe your behavior is inconsistent with that of a visitor. Perhaps your girlfriend could visit you in your country?